# How do i validate the text fields in UITable view cell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom cell:

```
class CustomOneCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var middleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var TextField: UIText!
```

}

In my `ViewController` i have used it as

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCellOne", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomOneCell
     cell.middleLabel.text = self.model.Fieldname 

    return cell
}
```

and there are around 15 cells in my `UITableView` and one them is Email.
Now for the `UITextField` of the label Email. I need to do the email validation. So how can i do the validation for that field..??
Any ideas will be really appreciated. For email Validation i have used.

```
func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {
    print("validate emilId: \(testStr)")
    let emailRegEx = "^(?:(?:(?:(?: )*(?:(?:(?:\\t| )*\\r\\n)?(?:\\t| )+))+(?: )*)|(?: )+)?(?:(?:(?:[-A-Za-z0-9!#$%&’*+/=?^_'{|}~]+(?:\\.[-A-Za-z0-9!#$%&’*+/=?^_'{|}~]+)*)|(?:\"(?:(?:(?:(?: )*(?:(?:[!#-Z^-~]|\\[|\\])|(?:\\\\(?:\\t|[ -~]))))+(?: )*)|(?: )+)\"))(?:@)(?:(?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[-A-Za-z0-9]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?)(?:\\.[A-Za-z0-9](?:[-A-Za-z0-9]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?)*)|(?:\\[(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9]|(?:[1-9][0-9])|(?:1[0-9][0-9])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:25[0-5]))\\.){3}(?:[0-9]|(?:[1-9][0-9])|(?:1[0-9][0-9])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:25[0-5]))))|(?:(?:(?: )*[!-Z^-~])*(?: )*)|(?:[Vv][0-9A-Fa-f]+\\.[-A-Za-z0-9._~!$&'()*+,;=:]+))\\])))(?:(?:(?:(?: )*(?:(?:(?:\\t| )*\\r\\n)?(?:\\t| )+))+(?: )*)|(?: )+)?$"
    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
    let result = emailTest.evaluateWithObject(testStr)
    return result
}
```

I am creating a registration form and all things for the form are loaded from API even name of the fields

Comment: This has been discussed many times here. Search on "UITextField email validation" or similar.

Comment: its all about the email validation for a text field that have either connected with IBOutlet.. My concern is i have same cell and using for different purpose. and i want to validate the email for the cell that have label named Email.

Comment: And exactly what part of that is the hard part? Where in the process are you actually running into trouble?

Comment: so i mean to say that how can i validate to that specific field that have label Email.............

Comment: Right, but how do you _want_ to validate it? Is the user pressing a Validate button? What moment in the life of the app are we talking about?

Comment: no its all while user moves to next field

Comment: Have you set the Textfield delegate to the CustomOneCell. Then check once the text is entered via the textFieldDidEndEditing method? Where does the isValidEmail function sit?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there are two problems here.

- At what moment in the life of the app shall we perform validation? You probably want to do this when the user ends editing on the text field. So you need to give the text field a *delegate* so you can detect `textFieldShouldEndEditing(_:)`, validate, and prevent ending editing if we're invalid.
- Once you've done that, how will you know that this is the email text field? Clearly the email text field needs to be *different* somehow from the others. An easy solution would be to give the email text field a `tag` value that you can check. All the other text fields might have `tag` value `0` while this text field would have `tag` value `1`.

Both those things would be configured in your `cellForRowAt:` implementation (exactly where your current code has a blank line). You know which row is the email row, so that is the one whose text field must be treated specially. Be sure to cover every row, though, because as you know, the cells are reused.

Comment: its a registration form. All things for the form are loaded from API even name of the fields. So i am in real confuse how to identify that field and validate the email..

Comment: But you clearly _have_ to identify the field. You didn't say _anything_ in your question about "all things for the form are loaded from API even name of the fields", and I have no way of knowing what that even means. I can only answer based on _what you reveal_. If you choose to hide the most important part of the problem, then it will be hidden and you won't get an answer. My answer is based on what you have chosen to reveal, and it correctly describes what you would need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Easy Way [Swift 5]

First Declare Array of your custom tableview cell

```
//MARK:- DECLARATIONS
var DataSource = 5 //Five textField in TableCell
var arrayOfCell = [tableViewCell]()
```

TableView Methods

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return DataSource
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "txtCell", for: indexPath) as! tableViewCell

    arrayOfCell += [cell]

    return cell

}
```

Button(Submit) When you want to validate your textFields

```
@IBAction func btnSubmit(_ sender: Any) {

    for i in 0..<arrayOfCell.count{
        if arrayOfCell[i].txtName.hasText != true{
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning!", message: "Please enter the text No: \(i)", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

}
```